# Use A Serializer Class Inside Other One In Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to have a serializers that use two model at once (If it possible)

**models.py**

```
class Club(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    clubname = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    scores = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ShowAllClubSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Club
        fields 

class ShowClubPictures(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Clubpictures
        fields = ['picture']
```

**views.py**

```
@api_view(["GET", ])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated, ))
def show_all_clubs_view(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        clubs = Club.objects.all()
        if clubs:

            for club in clubs:
                pictures = Clubpictures.objects.filter(clubid=club.id)
                serializer1 = ShowAllClubSerializer(club)
                serializer2 = ShowClubPictures(pictures[0])
            return Response(serializer1.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
          # return Response(serializer2.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Now I Have These In serializers1 and serializers2 Separately:

```
{
    "clubname": "Club Name",
    "location": "Somewhere",
    "scores": 5,
}

{
    "picture": "/media/images/Screenshot.png"
}
```

How can I take something like this in result:

```
{
    "clubname": "Club Name",
    "location": "Somewhere",
    "scores": 5,
    "picture": "/media/images/Screenshot.png"
}
```

Comment: You can't get from 2 models at once.
If you do so, you have to add one to other.

Comment: can you tell me how @starsseven

Comment: That's dictionary format so that you can merge it.

Comment: ok , Then how can I use it in Response? @starsseven

Comment: You can use as serializer1.data + serializer2.data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`nested serializers`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) to achieve that.

Your `ClubSerializer` would look something like this:

```
class ClubSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pictures = ClubPictureSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Club
        fields = ('clubname', 'location', 'scores', 'pictures')

class ClubPictures(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Clubpictures
        fields = ['picture']
```

assuming you have a `ForeignKey` from the `ClubPicture` to your `Club` with a `related_name` of `pictures`.

Also, on your view, you don't need to loop through `Club.objects.all()` and serialize each object individually - `ModelSerializer`/`Serializer` accept a [`many=True`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-multiple-objects) parameters that handles multiple objects already.